# NameError: global name 'interfaceName' is not defined even though it is

Tags: python, popen, nameerror

```
def putCardMon():
    interfaceName = input(('Type an interface name to put in monitor mode: '))
    print(colored('[+] ', 'green') + 'Trying to put the interface ' + colored(interfaceName, 'yellow') + ' in monitor mode\n')
    call(["sudo ifconfig " + interfaceName + " down; sudo iwconfig " + interfaceName + " mode monitor; sudo ifconfig " + interfaceName + " up"], shell=True)
    interfaceMonCheck = Popen(["iwconfig " + interfaceName + " | grep Mode | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0].rstrip()
    sleep (1)

---//lots of code before the putCardMon is called//---

interfacesList = Popen("ifconfig -a | grep Link | cut -d ' ' -f1", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0].rstrip()
print('The available interfaces are:\n' + interfacesList + '\n')
putCardMon()
print('Checking if ' + interfaceName + ' is really in monitor mode.')
if interfaceMonCheck == 'Managed':
    print('The interface ' + colored(interfaceName, "green") + ' is not in monitor mode! Check if you typed the interface name correctly or contact support.\n')
    putCardMon()
elif interfaceMonCheck == 'Monitor':
    print(colored('The interface ' + colored(interfaceName, "green") + ' is in monitor mode!'))
    pass
else:
    print(colored('There was an unexpected error. Contact support!\n', "red"))
    exit()
```

The script works fine, the function does its job, but then when it gets to the checking part everything goes downhill.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 76, in <module>
    print('Checking if ' + interfaceName + ' is really in monitor mode.')
NameError: name 'interfaceName' is not defined
```

How come interfaceName is not defined if the function that assigns a string to it has already been called and successfully assigned a value to it?

I searched stack overflow for the same error, but all the threads were answered and it was either an indentation error or the function was defined after being invoked, which neither is the case here.
I'm really out of options. I tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime`

> A variable which is defined inside a function is local to that
>   function. It is accessible from the point at which it is defined until
>   the end of the function

Your variable `interfaceName` is only defined inside the scope of your function `putCardMon()`. It ceases to exist outside the scope of the function. Hence you are getting the error.

If you want to use the variable outside the function body, consider returning it and saving its value.

```
def putCardMon():
    interfaceName = input(('Type an interface name to put in monitor mode: '))
    print(colored('[+] ', 'green') + 'Trying to put the interface ' + colored(interfaceName, 'yellow') + ' in monitor mode\n')
    call(["sudo ifconfig " + interfaceName + " down; sudo iwconfig " + interfaceName + " mode monitor; sudo ifconfig " + interfaceName + " up"], shell=True)
    interfaceMonCheck = Popen(["iwconfig " + interfaceName + " | grep Mode | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0].rstrip()
    sleep (1)
    return interfaceName

# Later you can do this
interfaceName = putCardMon()
```

Comment: Ooh so thats why.. Thanks man. I'll look into it and find a way to do that.
edit: Is it as simple as: return interfaceName and then printing it outside the function?

Comment: Yes, just added an example for you

Comment: What if I do: 
return variable 

and then print the variable name directly?

Comment: You could print directly without storing the value in a variable by `print(putCardMon())` but the function will be called everytime you print the value. If that is not the desired behavior ( which I think is the case), then you can store it in a variable and print it later  `print(interfaceName)`.

Comment: I tried that but I ran into a problem. There are 2 variables that need to get returned. How can I do that? I tried interfaceName = putCardMon() and then interfaceMonCheck = putCardMon() but the interface name isn't returned, only the last variable which is interfaceMonCheck. How could I return both variable strings and use it later?

Comment: You could return a tuple like `return (interfaceName, interfaceMonCheck)` and then read it later as `interfaceName, interfaceMonCheck = putCardMon()`. Read more about python tuples here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Comment: Sorry, I should've searched about it on my own before asking you again. I tried it, but the function putCardMon() gets called again when python executes the line `interfaceName, InterfaceMonCheck = putCardMon()`. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Make sure you are calling `putCardMon()` only once like `interfaceName, interfaceMonCheck = putCardMon()` so

Comment: Hi Bishal. I solved it by replacing the function call with  `interfaceName, InterfaceMonCheck = putCardMon()`. I guess I'll have to do it everytime I need to call it.

Comment: I did that. Thanks. I didn't know that the function call should assigned to the variables. I'm such a noob.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer and upvote it this helped you

Comment: You sure did man! :-] Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation so my upvote is displayed publicly, but it should be recorded in your account and reputation. Thanks again.